# Adding a line in javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function calcPrimesLoop() {
var primes = document.getElementById('primes');
primes.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" , /n , "+this.prime.nextPrime()));
calcPrimesDelay = setTimeout('calcPrimesLoop()', this.delay);
}
```

Okay so this is my code I am displaying an array of prime numbers. The issue is that I want each prime number to be on a seperate line but I am unable to do this. I have tried 
 /n and `&nbsp;` but they have not worked. It is being displayed in a textarea in html. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a backslash instead of a forward slash (`\n`)

EDIT: The below only applies to "normal" elements. For a textarea, you should be doing `primes.value += " , \n , "+this.prime.nextPrime();`

Additionally, newlines are collapsed in HTML (if you write text on multiple lines in your source code, it comes out on one line) but you can "fix" this using simple CSS:

```
primes.style.whiteSpace = "pre-wrap";
```

Spread the word about `white-space`! People need to stop using `<br />` tags just to get a newline!

Answer (score 3):

You could append a `br` element:

```
primes.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

...although usually the way you'd want to do this would be to put the primes in some kind of element container that you could style appropriately with CSS. A series of `div`s would automatically stack vertically:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(/*...your prime...*/));
primes.appendChild(div);
```

---

Two side notes on this line:

```
calcPrimesDelay = setTimeout('calcPrimesLoop()', this.delay);
```

First, it's almost always best to use function references, not strings, with `setTimeout`. So:

```
calcPrimesDelay = setTimeout(calcPrimesLoop, this.delay);
```

Second, unless you're declaring `calcPrimesDelay` somewhere you haven't shown, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: My only problem was it is meant to be \n not /n. I appreciate that divs are probably more practical but the line was for aseptic appeal. Thank you tho!